# Heroku file.exists? cannot find file that is just saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm transferring a WAV file from server to storage after manipulation, so I transfer the file to Heroku, then confirm the file exists before running the manipulation, however, File.exists? returns that the file does not exist, I feel its a naming or / path issue however cannot figure it.

I save the file URL in the file object which gives a URL example below

/uploads/wav_file/wbWavAudioFile/116/REff7e0b513481000322f530c849ddcccd.wav

On the HTML page, I can access and read this as well as download the file from the Heroku instance ( I re-rake the files on deploy this is proof of concept work and will use persistent storage after)

However, if I call

```
    if File.exists?(Rails.root+call.wbAudioFile.url)
                    puts "file exists"
                    #do some manipulation to file
    else
                    puts "file DOES NOT EXISIT"
    end
```

I get File not found and falls to does not exsist

is there a case-sensitivity issue? a / instead of \ issue?
Or am I needing to define the path differently?

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I circumvented this issue after considering that the production model would post the files to a Bucket, so just coded for the production specification instead of testing locally.